# How to avoid django test methods interfering with each other

Tags: django, django-tests

I am currently writing some django tests for my app1 and run into a weird error. I have a test method which simply performs a get request and checks the status_code of the response. That test works fine, but whenever this test is included in my test run, tests in app 2 suddenly fail. I have these type of get requests in other suits which work fine and cause no problems.

Taking out the test method, or simply the get request resolves the issue again. I tried to call different urls, resulting always in the same error. I also tried to give the test method different names without success.

test_folder
|_ **init**.py
|_ base.py
|_ test_app_1
|   |_ test_view1.py
|   |_ **init**.py
|_ test_app_2
      |_ test_view_2.py
      |_ **init**.py

```py
# test_folder/test_app_1/test_view1.py
from tests_folder.base import BaseTestCase

class CaseOneGIPTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')

    def test_app1(self):

        resp = self.client.get(reverse('planning1'))
        self.assertIs(resp.status_code, 200)

    def test_true(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


# test_folder/base.py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user('temporary', 'temporary')
```

Here an example of a failing test

```
# test_folder/test_app_2/test_view2.py
from tests_folder.base import BaseTestCase

class FailingTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def test_load_nearest_assets(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('urlblabla'),
                         {'data': "{\"key1\": \"value\", \"key2\": \"value\", \"key3\": \"value\"}"},
                         HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
        content = response.json()
        self.assertTrue(type(content['key4']['key5']) == list)
```

The following traceback is only present when the test method test_app1 is present and a get request is contained in the method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 209, in __call__
    self._post_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 908, in _post_teardown
    self._fixture_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1056, in _fixture_teardown
    connections[db_name].check_constraints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 245, in check_constraints
    self.cursor().execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "users_customuser" violates foreign key constraint "users_customuser_create_by_id_6250cba4_fk_users_customuser_id"
DETAIL:  Key (create_by_id)=(47) is not present in table "users_customuser".
```

Comment: can you show me your CustomUser model???

Comment: Also show an example of the failing tests.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? My customUser model is inheriting from AbstractUser and PermissionsMixin and has the attributes: - username; - first_name; - last_name; - date_joined; - email; - create_by; - assigned_to; - team; - birth_date; - is_active; - is_staff; - is_superuser;

Comment: please show the create_user function, I think you are not passing created_by.

Comment: the create_user function takes the following input: def create_user(self, username, password=None, email=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False):

Comment: Is it possible that django is not correctly creating a user in my test? When I check the content of my database there is no user in my table and therefore I get the key violation.